# prepareForSegue Never Called from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have an interesting bug in my code that makes selecting a `UITableViewCell`, to trigger a segue, a 50 tap process. Furthermore, the selection tends to only occur when those touches are simultaneously dragging down!

I have removed all the content from the cell in order to eliminate the possibility that this behavior is caused by content masking the selection area.

I have a feeling the root cause is a Storyboard problem rather than a code problem, because I do not see what code could trigger this behavior.

I would like any kind of insight with regards to steps to solve this.

Adding breakpoints to `prepareForSegue` informs me that the method never gets called, despite using the proper `Identifier`. I also tested originating the segues from both the `ViewController` and the `UITableViewCell` itself, to no avail.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "productDetailSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ProductDetailVC {
            if let productIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                destination.productArray.append(tableView.productList[productIndex])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom `UITableView` class:

```
class ProductTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var productList = [Product]()

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productList.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let product = self.productList[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductCell") as? ProductCell

        cell.picRequest?.cancel()
        cell.configureCell(product)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any additional views above your tableview?

Comment: Nope! Well I do, but I just tried removing it and that didn't solve the issue... @TimurBernikowich

Comment: So, there is not enough information to help you. You should paste some code.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich I don't know what to post! I don't want to copy paste everything. What code could be relevant?

Comment: You can paste minimal not working app, snippet or even *.xib.

Comment: Typically when I encounter interaction issues, it is gesture controllers which are holding up the detection of the touch events until they agree about which gesture was detected.

Comment: @ekscrypto I haven't registered any `UIGestureRecognizer`s though

Comment: @TimurBernikowich here's some code

Comment: @EricJohnson have you added breakpoint in prepareForSegue method?

Comment: I updated your question to reflect the code you added.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich I did and it never gets called.. Forgot to mention that

Comment: @EricJohnson and where is your selection code? Or your segue is defined in storyboard? Double check your segueIdentifier.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich The segue is defined in Storyboard and has the appropriate `Identifier`

Comment: @EricJohnson we have checked your code, problem is in your IB file for sure.)

Comment: @TimurBernikowich Yikes, knew it. I tried to debug using `Debug View Hierarchy` and everything is fine! Nothing is in front of the cell. I have `User Interaction Enabled` checked, my selection options are all standard.....

Comment: @Eric Remove your segue from cell and make segue from View Controller to other view controller and in your tableView didSelectcellforRowMethod, call performseguewithIdentifier

Comment: @SumitOberoi I already tried switching the origin of the segue, as stated in the question. Furthermore, I can't call `performSegueWithIdentifier` from a non-ViewController class.

Comment: @Eric What you can do here is perform didSelect for tableView and register for notification using NSNotification Centre and in your main controller listen for that notification, once you get that notification call your performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: @SumitOberoi yes I considered doing that or some sort of kvo but that would be more of a hack than a solution

Comment: It's a quite unusual pattern to have the datasource and delegate in the tableview rather than a tableviewcontroller, is that really your intention? What is your view controller hierarchy? What's your view hierarchy?